# Facebook pixel is reporting page views much lower than Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

[image]

My page views in Facebook pixel are only 10% of what I see in Google Analytics, I am using *adsmurai tagmanager* template and I am firing tags with the same triggers I use for Google Analytics.
My users are 99% on iOS.

What could be provoking such significant difference in page views?

Answer (score 0):

A few things there. Facebook's pageview script is tricky. It may not send a pv if the value is the same as in the last call. If it's an SPA site, that could be it. There are certainly ways to force a FB PV if needed. But you don't wanna do that blindly. You want to debug the issue properly.

Inspect network requests that you're sending to the FB endpoint and compare them to the requests you're sending to GA endpoint on various pageviews. Also actually look into the page urls that you have tracked in GA and compare to the similar dimension in FB.

This will likely give you insight into why or what pages are not being tracked.

Also, FB doesn't let you fire a pageview if it has already fired on this page (unless there was a history change with FB's history listener enabled), but there are ways to override this behavior. FB actually documents it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/tag_spa/

Answer (score 0):

Developer of the Adsmurai Facebook Pixel & Conversions API template on Google Tag Manager here.

You said 99% of your users are on iOS. In that case, please be aware of the new restrictions on data sharing that Apple released with iOS14: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/331612538028890?id=428636648170202

> Apple will begin to require that apps in the App Store that engage in
> what Apple defines as "tracking" to show a prompt to iOS 14 users, in
> accordance with their AppTrackingTransparency framework. Apple’s
> policy will prohibit certain data collection and sharing unless people
> opt into tracking on iOS 14 devices via the prompt. As more people opt
> out of tracking on iOS 14 devices, ads personalization and performance
> reporting will be limited for both app and web conversion events.

Based on your userbase, and assuming that a lot of people is opting out of tracking via such prompt, I think is safe to assume that the reporting difference is explained mostly because of iOS14's changes.